# How to make a low resolution image enlarge and fit it on to the Screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, imageview

When I created an Activity to display an image, the images with the low resolutions are simply ocupting the space it needs and not just fits the screen. This is my Activity:
[image: The Activity that I created]

The XML Code of the activity is this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/nick"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to the ImageView to fit the image to the screen with the ratio of the selected Image 
[image: Galary Activity]

The image in the Galary App is having a small resolution than the image that I used in my Activity ! So how is this done?

Answer (score 0):

Use a different scaleType and you can make it scale up.  But that can cause pixelation and other issues.  Its better to use a bigger image and scale down (or two images, full sized and thumbnail) than to scale most images up.

Edit:  Ok, on rereading your question, scale type isn't enough.  Try using this as a custom view:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class HeightScaleImageView extends ImageView {

    public HeightScaleImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HeightScaleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public HeightScaleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attributeSet, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageResource(int resId) {
        super.setImageResource(resId);
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        //Scale to parent width
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable != null) {
            height = width * getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() / getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        }
        super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used every scale options. Nothing works! yea pixelation is an issue but I want this feature on my App. Because the users might choose a pixellated image.

Comment: @FebinMathew check my edit.  You're right, scale type is insufficient for aspect ratio scaling to a match_parent with a wrap_content height.  The above code should work